# WARN:Node <nodename>has an empty run list.But I have added a runlist to the node?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Being new to Chef, I started a sample cookbook to create a file on a node.
Below is the code in my default.rb file

```
file 'home/ubuntu/sample.txt' do
  content 'this is test content'
  mode '0755'
end
```

I uploaded the cookbook to the server please find the screenshot below:

[image]

I also added the cookbook to the runlist under the specific node. When I try to knife bootstrap the node I get a warning saying the runlist is empty. I am not able to figure out what is missing. Below is the bootstrap command I am using

```
sudo knife bootstrap xx.xx.xx.xx --ssh-user ubuntu -i /home/ubuntu/keys/keyname.pem --sudo --use-sudo-password <password> -N testnodelatest
```

OUTPUT on executing above command:

```
 Starting the first Chef Client run...
54.40.1.69 Starting Chef Client, version 12.18.31
54.40.1.69 resolving cookbooks for run list: []
54.40.1.69 Synchronizing Cookbooks:
54.40.1.69 Installing Cookbook Gems:
54.40.1.69 Compiling Cookbooks...
54.40.1.69 [2017-02-14T01:36:22-05:00] WARN: Node testnodelatest has an empty run list.
54.40.1.69 Converging 0 resources
54.40.1.69
54.40.1.69 Running handlers:
54.40.1.69 Running handlers complete
54.40.1.69 Chef Client finished, 0/0 resources updated in 01 seconds
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `knife bootstrap` command does not specify a run list (`-r`). As this kicks off the Chef run, this is used as run list for this very first run.

I find it a bit weird that you already added a run list "under the specific node" (in your Chef Server, I assume?). If the node is already registered at the Chef server, then just don't use the `bootstrap` command. Instead, simply run `chef-client` on the node.

Comment: Hi Stephen, i did try that as well stil does not work , it says runlist is empty also i did add the runlist under the node on the chef server

Comment: Then specify the run list again using `knife node run list set ..` or in the Chef Server and start `chef-client` once again. Alternatively, use `knife bootstrap` one last time and supply the run list using `-r "recipe[hello_world_test]"`.

Comment: it worked when i added -r "recipe[hello_world_test] thank you so much :).  But i wanted to confirm if we should always mention it while using knife too ? Is it not sufficient if its added to the node on the chef UI console?

Comment: `knife bootstrap` uses the run list that you specify and the chef-client run will overwrite the previous setting in the Chef Server. So yes, never run `knife bootstrap` without specifying the run list.